# DbContext has been disposed when using nested LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Hello i have a problem which i cannot figure. Can anyone explain what the problem is and how it can be fixed ?

```
  ///--> get group members
    _adProfiles = groupsIds.Select(self => new Func<IEnumerable<AdProfileDto>>(() =>
    {
         return GetGroupMembersRepository.GetMembers(new GetGroupProfilesRequest { GroupId = self }).Profiles
             .Select(item => new Func<AdProfileDto>(() =>
                {
                 return new AdProfileDto
                   {
                      AccountName = item.AccountName.ToLower(),
                      DisplayName = item.DisplayName,
                      GroupId = self
                     };
                  })).Select(item => item.Invoke()).ToList();
              })).SelectMany(self => self.Invoke()).ToList();
```

Thank you all .

Comment: Can you show the code in the GetGroupMembersRepository.GetMembers, i think the problem is there.

Comment: What _is_ your problem?

Comment: yes ,, it was from the lower level  UoW ... thank you for the pointers. sorry i didn't posed the code but it would have been lots of code behind getMembers method. Again thank you  vasil oreshensk

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the dataaccess level forgot to add the .ToList() when i retrieve entries from db.